# Unable to install momentics IDE in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ide, software-installation

I've installed ubuntu 13.10 on my system, Now I am unable to start momentics IDE with ubuntu 13.10. I am getting below error while starting IDE.

```
./ide
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by installing libxtst6 from i386 architecture. Below are the full steps to install blackberry momentics IDE on ubuntu 13.10 x64

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386  libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 libxtst6  libasound2:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0.2/runtimes/xulrunner-10.0.2.en-US.linux-i686.tar.bz2
tar -xvf xulrunner-10.0.2.en-US.linux-i686.tar.bz2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=PATH_TO_XULRUNNER ldd *.so
```

That's all :)